# delete files from Google Drive Service account with the google drive gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, backup, discourse

We created a [synchronizer plugin](https://github.com/berlindiamonds/discourse-sync-to-googledrive) for discourse and it should synchronize backups to the google drive service account.
In order to keep the admin's google drive account clutterfree, we built a method at the end of the synchronizer, that is called `remove_old_files`

```
def remove_old_files
  google_files = session.files
  sorted = google_files.sort_by {|x| x.created_time}
  keep = sorted.take(SiteSetting.discourse_sync_to_googledrive_quantity)
  trash = google_files - keep
  trash.each { |d| d.delete(true) }
end
```

we memoized the session object before in an instance variable. So with `session.files` we get an array of all the files in our google drive account. In the `sorted` variable we sort them from new to old. In the `keep` variable we take the first few (the admin hat to set the quantity) and in the `trash` variable we define the rest. Until here the method works in the console.
Now in the documentation for the Google Drive gem there is a `delete` method for the File object:
 [File 'lib/google_drive/file.rb', line 182](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/GoogleDrive/File#delete-instance_method)

```
    def delete(permanent = false)
       if permanent
         @session.drive.delete_file(id)
       else
         @session.drive.update_file(id, { trashed: true }, {})
       end
       nil
    end
```

But when I try to delete via the rails console, it tells me `Success - nil` as if everything went fine. **But !** the files are still there when I count them or call them. Even though I tried to delete them setting `permanent = true` :/ 
  Why doesn't google delete the old backup files?

Comment: define "still there". What is the exact response from the delete (ie. is it a 200 or 204)? Are you deleting or trashing?